# Joomla menu displaying without decorator

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Since a few time Joomla menu in backend administrator is displaying without a decorator.

No errors are thrown by PHP, so I can't understand why is doing this way.

[image]

Comment: Could you see the browser console and check there are no errors? (press F12 and console separator)

Comment: Are you in 3.0.3 I think I am seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I digged in

Inside the #_menu table , there was a voic with a 'level' value very high like 4559099066767  .

The 'level' voice, is the level of nesting of category. That causes an infinite loop inside the code, giving the result as the screen.

My version was 2.5.9

Thanks

Comment: For future reference for people looking at this, try clicking the rebuild button in the menu manager.  ... But do you have any idea how you got such a level? Was it for the backend or front end menus? Was the menu item type for a core view or an extension?

Comment: Hello unfortunately I have no idea of what can be happened. I had some problem with menu and categories on my new website, and I had gone edit things manually.

But even if I could be wrong with the column I was editing , there could be no reason to put a value like the one found. So I suppose it was something generated by migration or code.

Anyway this line of code needs an error throwin, I took 3 hours of debugging to see a so simple thing!

Comment: Did you migrate this site from 1.5?

Comment: Hello I can't give you a sure reply. I came from a 1.5 installation, but I dno't remember if this voice come from migration or was created from scratch, thanks anyway

Comment: If it was migrated from 1.5 it can very easily have messed up nested sets.